# Resistance calculation problem

Tags: resistance

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNfGfh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You are given access to points A, B, and C, not access to the point between the resistors (inside the box). Given a volt meter, ammeter, and a power supply, find the resistance values of R1, R2 and R3.

Comment: Have you set up the equations yet?

Comment: Seriously, we're not going to do your homework, and I'm sure you've got material explaining how to do this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is homework question with no attempt at a solution.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have not had access to a computer since I posted the question, which is not a homework question. It is a question I was asked at an interview, and has been troubling me since. I had come up with an answer similar to user96037, and thought this site would be the place to see  how others would approach it. Did not mean to violate any rules.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 unknowns: R1, R2 and R3. Therefore, set up 3 different arrangements of the test equipment and use the measurements to set up 3 equations. Solve them for R1, R2 and R3. The necessary arrangements are not going to be unique but the solution will.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is applying ANY voltage thru ammeter thru any 2 points and measure voltage with the 3rd unused point to either end point, then one other config. measurement.

- or simply Rx=Vx/I
- Do for  x=1,2,3   trivial.
- done. get it? Its a current shunt with a volt reading.

  - there is no voltage drop on the resistor in series to the voltmeter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6iybd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I like this approach best. But perhaps it's only because it was the first thing that I "saw" as an approach.

Comment: oddly enuf, this exactly how ohmeters work with the voltage sensors having 1M input R or so... didn't stay up to watch finals of voting, yet we watched finale of Blacklist on PVR at 2am

Answer (score 0):

You can place a voltage between any two points using the power supply.  Measure the voltage (V) across the points, and the current (I) through one of the two points.  The resistance (R) measured across the two points is then R = V/I.

Measure the resistance between A and B to get...
RAB = R1 + R2

Measure the resistance between A and C to get...
RAC = R1 + R3

Measure the resistance between B and C to get...
RBC = R2 + R3

You now have three equations and three unknowns.

Note that for each measurement we measured the sum of two of the resistors in series.  The third resistor always had one end open, and therefore didn't affect the circuit since no current flowed through it

Combine the equations to solve for R1.
RAB + RAC - RBC = R1 + R2 + R1 + R3 - R2 - R3 = 2 * R1

So...
R1 = RAB/2 + RAC/2 - RBC/2

Now that we have R1 we can solve for R2.
R2 = RAB - R1 = RAB - (RAB/2 + RAC/2 - RBC/2) = RAB/2 - RAC/2 + RBC/2

Finally, since we know R2 we can solve for R3.
R3 =  RBC - R2 = RBC - (RAB/2 - RAC/2 + RBC/2) = RBC/2 - RAB/2 + RAC/2

Comment: This is similar to what I came up with, it appears I was on the right track and somewhere along the way got lost. I appreciate your answer!